# How to create a constructor for controller in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Am learning angularjs. I want to now is it possible to create constructor in angular? if it is yes, how to create constructor for controller? can any one help me on this thanks,

Comment: Basically, the `.controller(..)` method *is* the constructor. Maybe you can be more explicit about you have in mind and how the standard way of doing things doesn't fit that?

Comment: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/11/12/constructor-functions-and-controllers-in-angularjs.aspx

Comment: Create one function and assign the function to the controller, like: `angular.module('appName').controller('ctrlName', constructorFunction);`. But it'll be difficult to inject providers, if you want to minimize the code.

Comment: There is no concept of constructor in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way-

```
.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

    (function () {
        console.log() // Will log every time you go or refresh on dashboard controller

    }());

}]);
```